# How to access remote JSON data as a local array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm able to use Jquery's $.get function to access JSON data from another URL, but how can I use that data (as an array) elsewhere in my code?

Consider the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {        

    $.get("/some/other/url/that/returns/json", function(data){
        var d = eval(data);
    });

    alert(d);
    </script>
```

That's not functional, but it show's what I'd like to do.  Thanks in advance for your help/tips.

Comment: FYI, you can add a 'type' arg to your call and avoid the eval: `$.get('url', function(data){...},'json')`

Comment: jquery does eval internally..with the json dataType set

Comment: Only on the browsers that lack JSON parsers (i.e.: IE)

Answer (score 3):

Doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d;

$.get("/some/other/url/that/returns/json", function(json){
    d = json;
}, "json");
</script>
```

you'll get the `json` response, and if its already an array, you wont be needing to do anything else. Also, please **use `eval()` as little as possible**. (Not at all is great)

Be carefull that `d` wont have any value *until* there is a response, so your code should deal with that. Most likely, you'll call the function that uses `d` from within $.get("...", **function(json){}**,"json").

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d;

useArray = function(d){
    //Operations that involve the response
}

$.get("/some/other/url/that/returns/json", function(json){
    d = json;
    // Operate over "d" once your server
    useArray(d); 
}, "json");
</script>
```

Of course, as you now have all operations over `d` on a separate function, you could simply do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
useArray = function(d){
    //Operations that involve the response
}
$.get("/some/other/url/that/returns/json", function(json){
    useArray(json);
}, "json");
</script>
```

If you need to acces again to `d`, you should modify your code as needed. This is only a guide.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me away from eval(), voyager.  I've got a question about handling the "undefined" problem, though -- please see presleyster's answer & chime in if you can help.  Thanks again, JP.

Answer (score 0):

make d a global variable.  Or assign it to whatever needs to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> FYI, you can add a 'type' arg to your call and avoid the eval: $.get('url', function(data){...},'json')

Or you can use $.getJSON('url', function(data){...});